# How to output an iteration in a Jade template to a single line

Tags: pug, templating

I would like to iterate over an array of objects, and then have name and amount properties displayed on a single line, separated with commas and whitespace.

Entries look like this:

```
{
   name: 'SomeItem'
   amount: 2
},
{
   name: 'AnotherItem'
   amount: 1
},
...
```

I would like the end result to look like this:

**Your items:

  SomeItem: 1, AnotherItem: 2**

This is what I have so far:

```
h3 Your items:
    each item in items
       span.headline-item #{ item.name }: #{ item.amount },&nbsp;
```

Basically the problem is getting rid of the last comma, but asking more generally, what is the suggested way in Jade to circumvent the restriction of not being able to use 'if' inline?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to have the logic inside the interpolation:

```
each item, index in items
    span.headline-item #{ item.amount } #{ item.name }#{ (index < items.length - 1) ? ', ' : ''}
```